# How to Hide and Unhide Tabbar in JBTabbarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am using JBTabbarController in my iPhone project. I want to hide the UITabbar in some views. I can hide the tabbar, but how do I unhide it?

My code for hiding the tabbar:

```
 self.navigationController.JBTabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: try this [self. JBTabBarController.tabBar setHidden:TRUE];

Comment: on the view you want to show your tab bar on that view you need to impor the class of JBTabbarController and then if you create your tabbar in app delegate then use [appDelegate. JBTabBarController.tabBar setHidden:FALSE];

Comment: @eptdeveloper not working i tried it :(

Comment: @iOS: Its not working for me.